# Smarty: how to create a directory within templates and link?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I want to add a new folder/directory called "locations" into my default
templates directory in Smarty.

**Why?**

So that I can navigate to my new page which is:
*mywebsite.com/**locations**/new-post-here*

But I can't get the locations to work at all.

I have created the folder "Locations" already within my "templates" folder. This is what I have when I create the new class for Locations.

```
<?php
    require_once("libs/Smarty.class.php");
    $smarty = new Smarty();

    $smarty->assign("title", "Locations");
    $smarty->display("templates/locations.html");
?>
```

**Error I am getting**

> Internal server error, 500.

What else did I try?

```
<?php
    require_once("libs/Smarty.class.php");
    $smarty = new Smarty();

    $smarty->setTemplateDir( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../templates/locations/' );

    $smarty->assign("title", "Locations");
    $smarty->display("/locations/new-post-here.html");
?>
```

Not working!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear the where the file is stored in the directory of project.
Anyway if we assume the default folder of template is templates the only thing you've to do is

$smarty->display("${location}/{$templateFile}");

you don't must use / in front of path in display

```
<?php
    require_once("libs/Smarty.class.php");
    $smarty = new Smarty();

    $smarty->setTemplateDir( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../templates/locations/' );

    $smarty->assign("title", "Locations");
    $smarty->display("locations/new-post-here.html");
?>
```

But i'm not sure where your script is located

Comment: Nope, this still doesn't work. Still giving me an internal error. The post is stored within templates/locations. So I have a folder templates. In that folder I have a folder locations. And in that folder I should have the post... that post is giving me an internal server error

Comment: Enable the display_error so you can understand better which is the problem, you can use ini_set("display_error",1) on top of your PHP script

Comment: Well, still the same: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)